# React Hooks useState initial empty array value in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make typescript happy by giving the correct type. But I can't figure out the exact syntax.

```
export type CategoriesType = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
  courses: CoursesType[];
};

const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState<CategoriesType>([] as any);

useEffect(() => {
  const categories = Categories;

  for (const category of categories) {
    setSingleCategory(category);
  }
}, [singleCategory]);

return (
  singleCategory.courses !== [] ? ...
)
```

This code works. But typescript complains about usage of any. I would prefer to avoid using any.

Other tries:

I get error Property 'courses' does not exist on type 'CategoriesType | []'

```
  const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState<CategoriesType | []>([]);
```

Object is possibly 'undefined'.

```
const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState<CategoriesType>();
```

Comment: Would `const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState<CategoriesType[]>([])` work for your application?

Comment: Nope, I would get error Property 'courses' does not exist on type 'CategoriesType[]'. In return statement

Comment: What purpose does the array serve? Is it just a marker that "we don't have a category"?

Comment: Yes empty array, is initial value. Until Categories are fetched.

Comment: I don't display anything until categories are fetched.

Comment: Yes, In that case I would get error Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CategoriesType | (() => CategoriesType)'. Undefined is the same.

Comment: Yeah, obviously there will be an error which we'll then need to fix. I'm just trying to figure out what your design goals are. You've called this things "singleCategory", which implies there will only be one, but then you try to stick an array in it which only makes sense if there are multiple. You also call `setSingleCategory` multiple times, which is going to have them each overwrite the other. So is it supposed to be multiple of them, or just one? For multiple, an array makes sense for a default value. For a single, it does not. Either way, more code changes will be needed than that.

Comment: You right Nicholas. Single category is not an array. But I made it initial value as an array. And after that changed singleCategory into object. So no wonder I have trouble with typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set state like below.

```
const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState<CategoriesType[]>([])
```

Also in your return `singleCategory.courses` doesn't make any sense because `singleCategory` is array type not the object type. You should match your types for state definition and usage.